# How to get a circular layout in codenameone?

Tags: codenameone

If I want to have the layout which has the buttons in the circular form, 
how can I achieve that? We don't have circular layout in cn1 and using other
layout managers I don't know how to get the designated design as in the image
below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recall that a while back someone built a circle layout class and posted it but I couldn't find it. You can probably implement it by using the guide for creating a custom layout manager [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html#_building_your_own_layout_manager).

However in this case unless the layout changes it looks like you can reach it with a simple 3x5 table layout with some creative spanning/alignment.

I'm not sure which solution will be harder to implement though, building a layout manager isn't very difficult.